# Alignof(AbstractType) can't be compiled with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

The following code compiles fine with Clang/GCC, but reports errors with MSVC

> source_file.cpp(4): error C2259: 'FileUnit': cannot instantiate abstract class
>
> source_file.cpp(4): note: due to following members:
>
> source_file.cpp(4): note: 'void FileUnit::lookupValue(void) const': is abstract
>
> source_file.cpp(3): note: see declaration of 'FileUnit::lookupValue'

```
class FileUnit {
public:
  virtual void lookupValue() const = 0;
  void *operator new(size_t Bytes, unsigned Alignment = alignof(FileUnit)) {}
};
```

My question is: from a C++ specification point of view, is this an MSVC bug, or does Clang not comply with the standard?

Comment: Looks like MSVC bug. The standard only requires that the type passed to `alignof` be complete, and nothing says that an abstract class is not a complete type.

Comment: For reference, which versions of GCC, Clang, and MSVC are you comparing?

Comment: Clang: 3.9.0; MSVC: 19.00.24215.1; GCC: 4.9.3